# Log4j2 displays log in foreach within executor log but not in map method in executor log

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j

I am using Spark 2.3.0

When I use `foreach` within dataframe and logging I am able to see the logs in executor log. But why is it not printing the logs in `map` method?

```scala
val df = Seq((0)).toDF("a")

df.foreachPartition { iterator =>
  {
    iterator.map { row =>
      {
        val LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(getClass.getName)
        Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.INFO);
        LOGGER.info("Testing logger in executor")
      }
    }
  }
} //Not printing in executor log

df.foreachPartition { iterator =>
  {
    iterator.foreach { row =>
      {
        val LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(getClass.getName)
        Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.INFO);
        LOGGER.info("Testing logger in executor")
      }
    }
  }
} //Prints executor logs
```

What is the reason for this and is there a way to achieve this(I am using `Log4j2` with `log42.properties` file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foreach` is eager while `map` is lazy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Is there a work around to print it, or I will have to use foreach on output iterator after applying map?